# Vuetify: How to correctly set active item when using prepend on v-select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

When I use the **prepend-item** v-slot for the v-select component, selecting an item actives another item instead of the one that was selected.

Take this [code pen example](https://codepen.io/harrison-childs/pen/bGaxOVq) found on the vuetify docs. Notice that when you select any item in the list, the item that is 2 places above the selected item is the one that is highlighted. For example, selecting "Avocado" highlights the "Apples" item.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-select
        v-model="selectedFruits"
        :items="fruits"
        label="Favorite Fruits"
        multiple
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend-item>
          <v-list-item
            ripple
            @mousedown.prevent
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-icon :color="selectedFruits.length > 0 ? 'indigo darken-4' : ''">
                {{ icon }}
              </v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>
                Select All
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:append-item>
          <v-divider class="mb-2"></v-divider>
          <v-list-item disabled>
            <v-list-item-avatar color="grey lighten-3">
              <v-icon>
                mdi-food-apple
              </v-icon>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
  
            <v-list-item-content v-if="likesAllFruit">
              <v-list-item-title>
                Holy smokes, someone call the fruit police!
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
  
            <v-list-item-content v-else-if="likesSomeFruit">
              <v-list-item-title>
                Fruit Count
              </v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>
                {{ selectedFruits.length }}
              </v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
  
            <v-list-item-content v-else>
              <v-list-item-title>
                How could you not like fruit?
              </v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle>
                Go ahead, make a selection above!
              </v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

It looks as though in the above example, because there are 2 components in the template used in the v-slot (v-list-item and v-divider), the highlighted item will always be 2 above the item you select. It's like these prepended components are included in the index used to track the active item, hence it's always off by *n* number of prepended components.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue and highlight the correct item when selecting from the v-select?

Comment: This looks like a bug, you might be better off creating a bug report on vuetifys github page: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues

Comment: Thank you @Uchendu, I have now submitted a bug report.